# Hadoop: mapred.LocalJobRunner: MissingResourceException

Tags: java, maven, exception, hadoop, mapreduce

i'm trying to setup a simple mapReduce application with custom record-reader, mapper and reducer. Until (including) mapper it seems to work (when calling context.write I wrote the key-value pairs out on console for testing). 
Then I get the message

> "14/03/04 14:25:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%".

But after that I get in an infinite loop every 3sec

> "14/03/04 14:25:45 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: "

without a detailed message or anything other.

When enabling in my IDE to log all exceptions, I get the following exception after every message above:

> Exception 'java.util.MissingResourceException' occurred in thread
>   'communication thread' at
>   java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)

I defined the mapper as well as the reducer in the configuration of the job, but it seems that it couldn't find the reducer-class (?). Made a breakpoint inside the reducer, the program never comes to this line.

my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and my Job:

```
    Job job = new Job(new Configuration());
    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapperClass(DataFileMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(DataFileReducer.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(HourBlockInputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("..."));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("..."));
    job.submit();
```

Would be grateful for any suggestions,
best

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error (infinite loop). I solved by updating my pom.xml file.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Add above dependency in your my pom.xml file. May be it will help you. For me, it solved the problem.

If you have any questions, please comment.